# How do i set the input ( -, + ) based on action type ? laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How do i set the input ( -, + ) based on action type ? laravel
first of all look at ss [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urU7E.png)
I have a form with 5 columns, 5 inputs and i want to insert into my table the "suma" = "amount"(translated) based on what i select on (Tip actiune(0 = cheltuiala, 1 = plata, 2 = incasare)) input form.
So if i select 0 and 1 i want to insert into my table the "suma"(amount translated) with - sign operator. if i select option 2, i want to insert it like it is, with (+).
Does anyone knows how to do that?

This is my Controller function

```
public function saveProjDet(Request $request, IstoricProiecte $istoric, Colaboratori $colaborator)
    {
        $istoric->proiecte_id = $request->input('id_proiect');
        $istoric->action_type = $request->Status_Tranzactii;
        $istoric->colaboratori_id = $request->Colab_id;
        $istoric->suma = $request->input('suma');
        $istoric->data = $request->data;
        $istoric->save();
        return back();
    }
```

I tried to put (-) on $istoric->suma =  $request->input('-suma"); but obviously doesn t work, but i m asking you because i have no idea of how to do that.
So the point is to insert into database if my options are (1,2) to insert with (-) sign for "suma" column (which means amount again).

and this is part of my view.blade

```
<div class="mb-3">
<label class="form-label">Tip actiune(0 = cheltuiala, 1 = plata, 2 = incasare)</label>
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"  name='Status_Tranzactii'>
<option value="cheltuiala">0</option>
<option value="plata">1</option>
<option value="incasare">2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use something like `$request->input('-suma")` in your code, PHP looks for a variable literally named `-suma`, and it doesn't just add the `-` to the input. In your case, I might try something like this:

```
if ($request->input('Status_Tranzactii') === 2) {
   $istoric->suma = $request->input('suma');
}
else {
   $istoric->suma = $request->input('suma') * -1;
}
```

One thing to note: if you want to have a `+` or a `-` sign in front of each amount, that might be a good case to use an [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

Answer (score 0):

To put something on start of a string, you can use Laravel Helpers. But signs are different based on 0,1,2 condition. Just put them in a condition check them by their value.
Like when you select 0, the value of 0 is "cheltuiala" will be sent in controller. So check them by value inside controller and put your necessary code before save.

```
public function saveProjDet(Request $request, IstoricProiecte $istoric, Colaboratori $colaborator)
    {
        $istoric->proiecte_id = $request->input('id_proiect');
        $istoric->action_type = $request->Status_Tranzactii;
        $istoric->colaboratori_id = $request->Colab_id;
        $istoric->suma = $request->input('suma');

        if ($request->Status_Tranzactii == "cheltuiala" || $request->Status_Tranzactii == "plata") {
           $istoric->suma = Str::start($istoric->suma, '-');
        }
        else {
             $istoric->suma = Str::start($istoric->suma, '+');;
        }
        $istoric->data = $request->data;
        $istoric->save();
        return back();
    }
```